# changing the store state from component ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

I'm using selectors to select from the store

```
this.quizz = this.store.select(getSelectedQuizz);
```

I use the async pipe to read from this observable like this in the template

```
[*ngIf="quizz | async; let quizz"]
```

I only define the action and I didn't modify the reducer yet the template is a form when I save the form I dispatch an update action which is only defined in my actions with readonly but I notice that when ever I save the form and dispatch the action the store changed and I didn't specify any logic in the reducer to update the state for the update action yet I don't understand why.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 2-way data-binding to bind store state to a form which is a bad practice.
 Don't touch anything inside store state except by reducers.

Use spread operator to take a copy of state:

```
this.store.select(getSelectedQuizz).subscribe(quizz => 
    this.quizzModel = {...quizz };
);
```

Also take care about deep copies. Use something like `this.quizzModel = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(quizz ));` for deep copy.

**Hint:**
To avoid such kind of mistakes you can force state to be immutable.
Check [ngrx-store-freeze](https://github.com/brandonroberts/ngrx-store-freeze)

Comment: there is not another way creating a brand new observable instead of referring to the same observable

Comment: @HachimiAhmedAmine you don't need a brand new observable. just hold a copy of result of observable, like this: this.store.select(getSelectedQuizz).subscribe(quizz => this.quizz = {...quizz }